Unable to Receive Messages with InfiniBand UD (Unreliable Datagram) Communication
I am currently writing a sample program for RDMA communication using InfiniBand. The setup involves two servers, each running a single process. The goal is to send data from one server (Sender) to the other (Receiver) using Unreliable Datagram (UD) mode.
While communication works as expected in Reliable Connection (RC) mode, the Receiver does not receive data in UD mode and remains stuck waiting.
Environment

Server

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6


Device

1 x ConnectX-6 / server



Reproducible Example
You can find the test script I used here: https://gist.github.com/nariaki3551/45294aaae0d12ab2189ae546231d9cd3
This is a reproducible example using OpenMPI compiler and launcher.
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nariaki3551/45294aaae0d12ab2189ae546231d9cd3/raw/64bae0f75b72ce67d7f5e3d701b9dc299de71005/test_ud.cpp
mpicxx -o test_ud test_ud.cpp -libverbs
mpirun -n 2 serverA:1,serverB:1 -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH -x PATH $PATH ./test_ud 

output is here, we can see the Receiver did not receive the message sender posted.
Sender: (Rank 0) Starting MPI setup...
Receiver: (Rank 1) Starting MPI setup...
Sender: Using device mlx5_1
Receiver: Using device mlx5_2
Sender: Remote QP number: 57703, Remote LID: 32
Receiver: Remote QP number: 68825, Remote LID: 31
Sender: QP transitioned to INIT state
Sender: QP transitioned to RTR state
Sender: QP transitioned to RTS state
Receiver: QP transitioned to INIT state
Receiver: QP transitioned to RTR state
Receiver: QP transitioned to RTS state
Receiver: Waiting for a message...
Sender: Post sent request: Hello from RDMA Sender!, to qp_num 57703, lid 32

Issue
Although the Sender calls ibv_post_send(), the Receiver does not receive the data. ibv_poll_cq() on the Receiver side does not return any completion notifications, leaving the process stuck in a waiting state.
The same test code with Reliable Connection (RC) works correctly, indicating no physical or logical connection issues. I suspect there may be specific settings for UD that I am missing, but I am unsure how to debug this further.
Things I’ve tried

Ensuring ibv_post_recv() is called on the Receiver before ibv_post_send() on the Sender.
Transitioning QPs on both sides to the RTS state.
Verifying that the LID (receiver_lid) is non-zero.
Setting wr.wr.ud.remote_qkey on the Sender to match the Receiver QP’s PKEY.

Despite these checks, I’m unable to identify the root cause. Are there any common pitfalls or settings specific to UD communication that I should verify? Any advice or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
